# How do MAC addresses get burned into devices during manufacturing?

Tags: ethernet, burning, mac-address

I'm interested in the steps necessary to manufacture an IP-capable device - say an Ethernet card. Manufacturing the hardware is pretty straight forward since all of the devices are exactly the same and there are well-established ways to do this. Next you load up any firmware the device needs - again pretty straight forward as all of the devices can be treated identically.

But now you have an issue: each card needs to have its unique MAC address burned into it. I'm interested in whether the cost of doing this custom process relative to the other things (such as simply loading in firmware) is higher because it's "custom"? I'd imagine that you could simply do this by having a "burner" simply burn the next number in the sequence (for that vendor's unique prefix) to the card.

Are things as simple as that and am I just overthinking things here? Is assigning a MAC address a very very low cost process? Are there any other customizations that your typical device will need done to it?

Comment: There's no "burn" operation.  That's a chemical reaction induced by lasers on writable optical media.  One common method I'm aware of is storing board specifc data such as MAC address and serial number in a serial EEPROM, which are low-pin count, low-capacity (<128 Kbits), low-cost storage devices.  These chips are often programmed in bulk (using a chip "progammer" device) and then installed on the boards.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that there's a difference between writing optical media and burning a PROM.

So I guess that means that large numbers of chips can be programmed at low cost and then simply placed on a board as just another component.

128 Kbits seems like an awful lot of space for a MAC address and serial number. Is anything else typically written to these devices?

Comment: The *less than* 128 Kbit number was just a number for typical serial EEPROM size.  This [semi-custom chip](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/products/memory/serialEEPROM/MAC.html) has 1.5Kbit capacity.

Comment: I did notice the "less than", but even so, 1.5K is wayyyyyy more space than really necessary. Is there anything else typically written to these chips, or do they end up empty except for a 48 (or sometimes 64) bit address?

Comment: I had a client whose board had a 1 Kbit serial EEPROM for storing the MAC address.  That's all that they wanted stored there.  Not even a CRC32 or checksum to validate the data.  Another client's board stored the MAC address in the U-Boot environment in NAND Flash.